# SWReveal Menu on Multiple View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am developing an application where I have multiple view controllers who should be able to access the reveal side menu. I am not using the navigation controller though, and am just using regular view controllers and opening the menu with a button. On the first screen, which I have linked with sw_front, it works.

If I go to another screen which I added an sw_front segue to too, it won't work. How can I get it to work on all view controllers which are linked? It seems to only work on one...

Screenshot of storyboard:
[Storyboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ded4F.png)

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: I mean, it's not really a code thing. I wouldn't know which code to show. It's a storyboard thing, I am assuming. The way I set up the view controllers or something?

Comment: @TroyT Here is a screenshot of the storyboard https://imgur.com/BjbQkBB

Comment: @EthanFine check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add reveal view controller before it where you want like first view controller .

And one more thing if you are Access from SW_rear ,then set_push method gave by swrevealviewcontroller.

[image]

Comment: if u like to access from sw_rear the use my suggestion other wise you have to add again swrevealview controller like your home screen :)

Comment: So, I have to set a navigation controller in order to do it? Is there a way to set a navigation controller without a top bar? Basically like a normal view controller?

Comment: [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES]; try this

Comment: [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES]; try this to

Comment: you asked another question in it but no problem if its solved your problem accept my answer :) ,happy coding

Comment: It seems as if it worked! Thank you very much. Just ended up ticking off the box in the navigation controller, haven't really used it before so had no idea there was a tick off for it :)

Comment: @EthanFine happy coding :)

Comment: @KishoreKumar Can you please have a look over this question of mine... http://stackoverflow.com/q/35699581/5395919 . I am quite struggling on this issue.

Comment: @KishoreKumar, I also encounter problem with this RevealViewController. Could you please take a look to my question? I look many youtube tutorials of this but not work. Here is my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42172297/slideoutmenu-remove-navigation-bar/42174197#42174197