# SWRevealViewController pushing FrontVC is not causing animation and not responding to notifications

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, segue, swrevealviewcontroller

I am working on SWRevealViewController in which I have a scenario in which -

Demo code link - https://www.dropbox.com/s/02fjub838hv95cr/SWRevealVC.zip?dl=0

**1)** I have to present a ViewController's view*(NotificationVC in my storyboard)* in my FrontVC.

**2)**This childVC's View has a button*(createNotification)* which is connected to another viewController*(createNotificationVC)* via *custom segue(SWRevealViewControllerSeguePushController)*,which has a back button

**3)**Pressing the back button user returns to the frontVC again with some message to be passed to the FrontVC.

For this message passing,I am using notification Pattern.

In my frontVC -

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.revealViewController().delegate = self

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

        if self.revealViewController() != nil
        {

            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
        }

        let NtfctnVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NtfctnVC")

        addChildViewController(NtfctnVC!)
        NtfctnVC!.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,self.customView.frame.width, self.customView.frame.height)
        customView.addSubview(NtfctnVC!.view)//add the childVC's view
```

NtfctnVC!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

```
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "methodOfReceivedNotification:", name:"NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
    }
    func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        //Take Action on Notification
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        print(userInfo!["sentTag"] as? Int)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)


    }
```

In the createNotificationVC's back button action,I have -

```
 @IBAction func bck(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let frontVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("frontNVC") //frontNVC is the navigation controller of frontVC

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("NotificationIdentifier", object: nil, userInfo: ["sentTag":2])
        self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(frontVC, animated: true)//here the frontVC is presented with no animation.
}
```

**Problem -**

1)The animation while performing custom segue is not been shown.
2)Notifications message are not being passed to the frontVC.

Please help me regarding this as I have tried lot many stuff & googling, but in vain. Thanks.

[image]

This shows my SWR connection with front & rear VC

[image]

This shows my NotificationVC/childVC's connection. *Mark:*ChildVC button connected via custom segue to createNotificationVC.

Comment: can you explain it clearly little bit?

Comment: @KishoreKumar Bro exactly, if you can please download the source code and run it once, you will get to know what I am saying. Can you please see the source code once? I have shared a link.

Comment: ok wait a minute i will check it @G.Abhisek

Comment: @KishoreKumar Thanks a lot bro.

Comment: bro i can run that code your pods_swrevealVC.framework is missing.can you tell me what you want exactly :) @G.Abhisek

Comment: @KishoreKumar Bro the animations are not working when I move from the child vc's view to the createNotificationVC & please check the createNotificationVC's back button, If i want to pass some messages via notification. that's too is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104871/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-g-abhisek).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.SWRevealViewController have SW_Front & SW_REAR .

2.To use this you need to implement this hierarchy

->swrevealviewcontroller -->swfront--->viewcontroller
                         -->swrear---->viewcontroller

3.in your case why that code doesn't work means .

4.From sw_rear  you have to use this animation ,then it will work sure.

[image]

Comment: As you can see ChildVC's button connected via custom segue to createNotificationVC. And NotificationVC/childVC whose view I have added in the frontVC is also added to the sw_front VC stack , so why is it so?

Comment: Ya bro I had a look.. I have a requirement like that itself. I am connecting like that because I want my createNotificationVC to act as a frontVC when user swipes & it should show the slide menu.

Comment: Please give suggestions bro

Comment: ok add one new swrevealviewcontroller ,then add front as your createnotification view ,sw_rear to your notification screen now use that animation try this.

Comment: But while moving to the old frontVC it would result in error!!

Comment: @G.Abhisek super happy coding :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104950/discussion-between-g-abhisek-and-kishore-kumar).