# SlideOutMenu remove Navigation Bar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swift3, uinavigationbar, swrevealviewcontroller, xcode8.2

I use SWRevealViewController for my project. Currently, the problem is that when the project starts, Navigation bar show with title of "MyApp". But, navigation bar disappears when I click on Home

[image]

[image]

[image]

If I add a Navigation Bar in view controller, there will be 2 navigation bars at first run. One navigation will automatically disappear when I click on **Home** link.

How to do to get the first image appearance when I click on Home link? I'm using **Swift 3**.

Answer (score 0):

You could try set the navigation bar to not hidden in the `viewWillAppear`.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

    // ...
}
```

However I presume the reason the navigation bar is hidden is because the controller is being presented modally and not being pushed onto the main navigation controller. If this is the case, then you will need to probably do something with the `SWRevealViewController` and push the controller onto the main navigation controller.

Check out the Basic API usage for `SWRevealViewController` [here](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController#basic-api-description) and [here](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu#code-less-storyboard-implementation) is an alternative that has codeless storyboard implementation and is very easy to configure.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I try your code but not work. Now, I'm looking your reference links. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I'm not sure the way I solved is right or wrong. But, it works for me.
I remove default Navigation Bar by disabling the bar visibility. Then, I add new Navigation Bar in Home page. After I run the app, my new Navigation Bar appears when I press on the Home button.